# Get items that were created exactly one, two, n... years ago

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

From some table I should select items, that were created exactly at least one year ago - at the same month and day as today. So, items created at 2011-10-10, 2013-10-10 will suit, but not at 2014-10-10.

The following query works just fine, but maybe there is a more elegant way? Thanks in advance.

```
select * from myTable 
where 
    DATEPART(MONTH, CreatedOn) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) -- item was created at the same month
    and DATEPART(DAY, CreatedOn) = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) -- and at the same day
    and DATEDIFF(YEAR, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) >= 1           -- and at least one year ago
```

Comment: Is this going to be a common query or is this more of a rare/one-off thing? And should February 29th have any special handling (thinking about both leap and non-leap years)?

Comment: Just an FYI.    SQL Server performs *much* faster if you DECLARE those date values before your SELECT.    Taking things like `DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())` and `DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())` and  setting that into a declaration and passing that variable in your select statement, the SQL will be much more performant.

Comment: @Jason Right you are, thank you

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It will be executed every day, once a day. Hm, I've forgotten about 29th of February... Those records, created on 29th should also be present event if there are only 28 days in February this year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (if possible) change the table to have an extra, [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx), defined as:

```
DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,CreatedOn,0),CONVERT(date,CreatedOn))
```

Say, called `AnniversaryDate`. This has the effect of "normalizing" the dates into the year 1900. This also treats 29th February the same as 28th February (both get normalized to 28th).

You now create an [index on this computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189292(v=sql.100).aspx), making searches within it quick and easy. You use the same formula to transform `GETDATE()` into a "normalized" date for searching this data. All you have to do now is exclude results that occurred this year, which should be as simple as one extra filter. So your final query wound be:

```
AnniversaryDate = DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,GETDATE(),0),
                  CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) and
CreatedOn < CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

(I'd probably create a single index on both AnniversaryDate and CreatedOn, to maximally benefit from this query).